# How to add new CSS rule to inner id

Tags: html, css

Wasn't exatcly sure how to name the title but basically what I'm looking for is how to add a specific CSS style to a class inside a td tag that overrides the style specified for the td tag. Below is the relevant parts from my html file and my CSS.

```css
.content
{
   height:auto;
   padding:0 0 10px 0;
}

.content th
{
   font:bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color:#6878AB;
   text-align: left;
   padding:5px 0 0px 10px;
}
.content td
{
   font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color:#3f4244;
   padding:5px 0 0px 10px;
   font-size:13px;
}

.DisplayRow2
{
   color:green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
<link href="meny.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="content">
<table boarder=0>

<tr>
  <td class="DisplayRow1" id="DisplayRow1">Text 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="DisplayRow2" id="DisplayRow2">Text 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
 </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

So the problem is that the style for the text inside the second td is exatcly the same as the first one. I've tried several variations in my CSS, but I'm not a web dev so I'm mostly just doing trial and error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following solution solved by the Specificity. In this case you have to define a more specific CSS rule to override another existing rule. An alternative to the more specific CSS rules is the `!important` property. You can find more information about this topic here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

```css
.content {
  height:auto;
  padding:0 0 10px 0;
}
.content th {
  font:bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color:#6878AB;
  text-align: left;
  padding:5px 0 0px 10px;
}
.content td {
  font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color:#3f4244;
  padding:5px 0 0px 10px;
  font-size:13px;
}
.content td.DisplayRow1 {
  color:blue;
}
.content td.DisplayRow2 {
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <table boarder=0>
    <tr>
      <td class="DisplayRow1" id="DisplayRow1">Text 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="DisplayRow2" id="DisplayRow2">Text 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to explain why this does work (specificity and all)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Could have sworn I already tried this though, but apparently not

Answer (score 1):

add `!important` to second td, like this:

```css
.content
{
   height:auto;
   padding:0 0 10px 0;
}

.content th
{
   font:bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color:#6878AB;
   text-align: left;
   padding:5px 0 0px 10px;
}
.content td
{
   font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color:#3f4244;
   padding:5px 0 0px 10px;
   font-size:13px;
}

.DisplayRow2
{
   color:green !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
<link href="meny.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="content">
<table boarder=0>

<tr>
  <td class="DisplayRow1" id="DisplayRow1">Text 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="DisplayRow2" id="DisplayRow2">Text 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
 </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Never heard of !important before

Answer (score 1):

use !important

```
.DisplayRow2
 {
    color:green !important;
 }
```

this is override the previous color code value.

Comment: You shouldn't use `!important` when it's not necessary to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity
  Change your code to this, This one's ideal

```
td.DisplayRow2 {color:green;}
```

or you could do this, try to minimize use of !important tag as it'll increase complications and it is not a good practice to override css rules using this,

```
.DisplayRow2 {color:green !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like this.

You can already define `color` css rule in class `.content td`. So `.DisplayRow2` class css are not working.

Add below css rule in your css

```
.DisplayRow2{
    color: green !important;
}
```

```css
.content
{
   height:auto;
   padding:0 0 10px 0;
}

.content th
{
   font:bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color:#6878AB;
   text-align: left;
   padding:5px 0 0px 10px;
}
.content td
{
   font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color:#3f4244;
   padding:5px 0 0px 10px;
   font-size:13px;
}

.DisplayRow2{
   color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
<link href="meny.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="content">
<table boarder=0>

<tr>
  <td class="DisplayRow1" id="DisplayRow1">Text 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="DisplayRow2" id="DisplayRow2">Text 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
 </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```